# Supply JavaScript date to Nashorn script

Tags: javascript, java, date, nashorn

I am working on an API in Java that allows users to write scripts and access a specific set of methods that are passed in (in the form of an API object) by the Nashorn script engine.

I want to, in the JavaScript, call a function getDate(), which will return some arbitrary date (as a native JavaScript date) that's provided from the Java side.

I have tried simply putting an org.java.util.Date on the API object, but that won't behave like a JS date. The goal is to make this as simple as possible for end-users who are experienced with JS.

Java Example:

```
public class MyAPI {
    public void log(String text){
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        // Return something that converts to a native-JS date
    }

    public static void main(){
        // MyClassFilter implements Nashorn's ClassFilter
        ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(new MyClassFilter());
        ((Invokable) engine).invokeFunction("entryPoint", new MyAPI());
    }
```

JavaScript example

```
function entryPoint(myApi){
    var date = myApi.getDate();
    myApi.log(date.getMinutes());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nashorn engine has objects it uses internally which represent the Javascript objects. As you have guessed the `java.util.Date != new Date()` (in javascript). The engine uses a class called `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDate` to represent its JS date.

If I were building this out I would not have the `NativeDate` constructed in the Java but instead have a wrapper in Javascript for the `MyApi` object which would contain a few other native JS methods, such as `getDate()`.

```
var MYAPI_JAVASCRIPT = {
    log: function() {
        print(arguments);
    },
    getDate: function() {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

You could then pass that object as the method parameter.

---

However if your really set on using the `NativeDate` in your Java code then you can construct one like so:

```
public NativeDate getDate() {
    return (NativeDate) NativeDate.construct(true, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option did it!
FYI, I needed to do it that way because the methods in the API call a whole lot of Java code.

Comment: @MoscowModder FYI if your looking for the native class for any Javascript object you can use `print(Date.prototype)`, of course replace `Date` with whatever Object your looking for. In the Date case you get something like: `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDate$Prototype@b7f23d9`

Answer (score 3):

jdk.nashorn.internal.* packages are nashorn *internal implementation* classes. There is no guarantee that these won't be changed or be removed between JDK versions. Besides with a security manager around, accessing these packages from java code directly would result in SecurityException being thrown! With jdk9 modular jdk, these packages are not exported packages from nashorn module and so javac won't even compile your code in jdk9!

I'd recommend using JS wrapper (solution 1) in the answer by user "ug_". If you do have to call from Java, you can use API exported from jdk.nashorn.api.scripting package.

If "engine" is your javax.script.ScriptEngine of nashorn, then you can do something like the following:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;

..

public Object getDate() {
    // get JS Date constructor object - you can get once and store
    // as well/
    JSObject dateConstructor = (JSObject) engine.eval("Date");
    // now do "new" on it
    return dateConstructor.newObject();
}
```

With that, your JS script can call "getDate()" on your API object and get a JS
Date object. Note that you can also pass constructor arguments to newObject
method call (it is a Java variadic method).